# How to redirect after form submission to homepage and send a confirmation email

Tags: php, html

Can you guys please help me with the redirect after form submission and email confirmation?this is a hotel reservation code.I have tried mostly everything...i searched this thing a lot on this forum but i couldnt fix my problem :(((

`````
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    $code1 = $_POST['code1'];
    $code  = $_POST['code'];
    if ( $code1 != "$code" ) {
        $msg = "Invalide code";
    } else {

        $con   = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "", "hotel" );
        $check = "SELECT * FROM roombook WHERE email = '$_POST[email]'";
        $rs    = mysqli_query( $con, $check );
        $data  = mysqli_fetch_array( $rs, MYSQLI_NUM );
        if ( $data[0] > 1 ) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('User Already in Exists')</script>";

        } else {
            $new     = "Not Conform";
            $newUser = "INSERT INTO `roombook`(`Title`, `FName`, `LName`, `Email`, `National`, `Country`, `Phone`, `TRoom`, `Bed`, `NRoom`, `Meal`, `cin`, `cout`,`stat`,`nodays`) VALUES ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[nation]','$_POST[country]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[troom]','$_POST[bed]','$_POST[nroom]','$_POST[meal]','$_POST[cin]','$_POST[cout]','$new',datediff('$_POST[cout]','$_POST[cin]'))";
            if ( mysqli_query( $con, $newUser ) ) {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Your Booking  has been sent,you will receive a confirmation email shortly')</script>"                                  } else {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Error adding user in database')</script>";

            }
        }

        $msg = "Your code is correct";


    }
}
    ?>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>````
`````

Comment: You're wide open to sql injection. You should use prepared statements to make your statements safe to use.

Comment: Please format the code to make it readable i.e. not having to scroll left/right

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this :

```
  $to = "jatinjhambji@gmail.com";
  $subject = "Confirmation mail";
  $message = " This message is to confirm your account has been created. "
  $headers = "From: youremail@example.com" . "\r\n" .
              "CC: somebodyelse@example.com";
  if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
      header('Location: /yourredirectionpage.php');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this one, if it could help you -

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $code1=$_POST['code1'];
        $code=$_POST['code']; 
        if($code1!="$code"){
            $msg="Invalide code"; 
        }else{
            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hotel");
            $check="SELECT * FROM roombook WHERE email = '$_POST[email]'";
            $rs = mysqli_query($con,$check);
            $data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
            if($data[0] > 1) {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('User Already in Exists')</script>";
            }else{
                $new ="Not Conform";
                $newUser="INSERT INTO `roombook`(`Title`, `FName`, `LName`, `Email`, `National`, `Country`, `Phone`, `TRoom`, `Bed`, `NRoom`, `Meal`, `cin`, `cout`,`stat`,`nodays`) VALUES ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[nation]','$_POST[country]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[troom]','$_POST[bed]','$_POST[nroom]','$_POST[meal]','$_POST[cin]','$_POST[cout]','$new',datediff('$_POST[cout]','$_POST[cin]'))";

                if (mysqli_query($con,$newUser)){

                    $to = "test@example.com";
                    $subject = "Test Mail";
                    $message = "Your account has been created. "
                    $headers = "From: youremail@example.com" . "\r\n" .
                                "CC: xyz@example.com";
                    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
                        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Your Booking  has been sent,you will receive a confirmation email shortly'); window.location = "http://example.com/homepage.php";</script>"                        
                    }                                 

                }else{
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Error adding user in database')</script>"; 
                }
            }
            $msg="Your code is correct";
        }
    }
?>
        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

Check the other answers for email confirmation. **Nidhi Gupta's** answer might help you.

Add a ; (semi-colon) after nidhi gupta's message variable ($message) to fix th error.

You can add:

```
header("Location: file.php");
```

Note: file.php should be changed to your location which you want it to be redirected to.
Use this before any include func.

And you might use this for better viewing:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $code1=$_POST['code1'];
        $code=$_POST['code']; 
    if($code1!="$code") {
        $msg="Invalide code";
    } else {
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hotel");
        $check="SELECT * FROM roombook WHERE email = '$_POST[email]'";
        $rs = mysqli_query($con,$check);
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
        if($data[0] > 1) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('User Already in Exists')</script>";
        } else {
        $new ="Not Conform";
        $newUser="INSERT INTO `roombook`(`Title`, `FName`, `LName`, `Email`, `National`, `Country`, `Phone`, `TRoom`, `Bed`, `NRoom`, `Meal`, `cin`, `cout`,`stat`,`nodays`) VALUES ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[nation]','$_POST[country]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[troom]','$_POST[bed]','$_POST[nroom]','$_POST[meal]','$_POST[cin]','$_POST[cout]','$new',datediff('$_POST[cout]','$_POST[cin]'))";
        if (mysqli_query($con,$newUser)) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Your Booking  has been sent,you will receive a confirmation email shortly')</script>"                                  }
        } else {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Error adding user in database')</script>"; 
        }
            $msg="Your code is correct";
            header("Location: file.php");
    }

 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please below code

```
if (mysqli_query($con,$newUser))
 {
    sentBookingMail($mailData);
    header('Location: next_page.php');
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Your Booking  has been sent,you will receive a confirmation email shortly')</script>"; 
  } else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Error adding user in database')</script>"; 

  }

  function sentBookingMail($mailData){
   // your mail code will be here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Error Fixed:

You can add like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $code1=$_POST['code1'];
    $code=$_POST['code']; 
    if($code1!="$code")
    {
        $msg="Invalide code"; 
    }
    else
    {

        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hotel");
        $check="SELECT * FROM roombook WHERE email = '$_POST[email]'";
        $rs = mysqli_query($con,$check);
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
        if($data[0] > 1) 
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('User Already in Exists')</script>";
        }
        else
        {
            $new ="Not Conform";
            $newUser="INSERT INTO `roombook`(`Title`, `FName`, `LName`, `Email`, `National`, `Country`, `Phone`, `TRoom`, `Bed`, `NRoom`, `Meal`, `cin`, `cout`,`stat`,`nodays`) VALUES ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[nation]','$_POST[country]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[troom]','$_POST[bed]','$_POST[nroom]','$_POST[meal]','$_POST[cin]','$_POST[cout]','$new',datediff('$_POST[cout]','$_POST[cin]'))";
            if (mysqli_query($con,$newUser))
            {
                
                $to = "test@gmail.com";
                $subject = "Confirmation mail";
                $message = " Account has been created. ";
                $headers = "From: sender@example.com" ;
                if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
                {
                    header('Location: /redirect.php');
                }   
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Your Booking  has been sent,you will receive a confirmation email shortly')</script>"    ;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Error adding user in database')</script>"; 
            }
        }
        $msg="Your code is correct";

    }
}
```

Comment: You can add headers like:

$headers = 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";